# What's the difference between ‘old-fashioned’, ‘obsolete’ and ‘antiquated’?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

What's the difference between 'old-fashioned', 'obsolete' and 'antiquated'?for an example,an old-fashioned steam train was not in use any more.could i say 'an obsolete steam train' or 'an antiquated steam train'? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster dictionary gives the meaning of 'antiquated' as 'ourmoded' or 'obsolete', which suggests these words are synonyms:

> ***antiquated*** : outmoded or discredited by reason of age : old and no longer useful, popular, or accepted (...) obsolete

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antiquated

> ***obsolete*** 1 a : no longer in use or no longer useful

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete

Now, whereas **old-fashioned** is actually defined as outmoded/ obsolete in one sense, that is not the sole meaning of the term:

> ***old-fashioned***
>
> 1 a : of, relating to, or characteristic of a past era [...]
>
> b : adhering to customs of a past era
>
> 2 : outmoded

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old-fashioned

The subtle difference is that what is described as "old-fashioned" may often simply show a preference for  conservative ideas, traditional styles or customs and practices of a past era, and *need not necessarily* mean  outdated or antiquated, in the sense of no longer being useful or relevant in the modern age:

> Alice and Bob hold the old-fashioned view that a husband and wife must make their best effort to save their marriage from divorce.
>
> The Simpsons are a very traditional firm with an old-fashioned way of doing business.

However, 'old-fashioned' can also be used as a direct and exact synonym of 'antiquated', ' obsolete' and 'outmoded', depending on the context.

So if the old-fashioned steam train is absolutely outdated and no longer used for its original purpose in your context, then you can say "antiquated steam train" or "obsolete steam train" -- but do note that steam trains are [still in regular use](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=steam+trains+are+still+in+regular+use+in+some+parts+of+the+world)  in some parts of the world!

Comment: Just a small addition to this excellent answer: _obsolete_ means 'of a type no longer considered fit for use'.

Comment: @KateBunting may I suggest that you upvote the excellent answer?